# Seemingly silly query about parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working in ASP.NET MVC 4 with C#, and i'm trying to turn the parameter of one ActionResult method into a variable for use in another method. So I have this for example:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int ser)
    {
        var invoice = InvoiceLogic.GetInvoice(this.HttpContext);

        // Set up our ViewModel
        var pageViewModel = new InvoicePageViewModel
        {
            Orders = (from orders in proent.Orders
                      where orders.Invoice == null
                            select orders).ToList(),
            Callouts = (from callouts in proent.Callouts
                        where callouts.Invoice == null
                            select callouts).ToList(),
            InvoiceId = ser,
            InvoiceViewModel = new InvoiceViewModel
        {
            InvoiceId = ser,
            InvoiceItems = invoice.GetInvoiceItems(),
            Clients = proent.Clients.ToList(),
            InvoiceTotal = invoice.GetTotal()
        }
    };
        // Return the view
        return View(pageViewModel);
    }
```

I need that int ser to somehow become "global" and its value become available to this method:

```
    public ActionResult AddServiceToInvoice(int id)
    {

        return Redirect("/Invoice/Index/");
    }
```

As you can see in my return statement just above, I get an error as I am not passing the variable "ser" back to Index, but I need it to be the same value that was passed to Index when the action was called. Can anyone assist?

Comment: how do the methods correlate?

Comment: You could look in any sample how Urls to actions are generated in views... If samples are not available - post view's code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

When you construct your link to that method, you need to ensure you are passing your variable `ser` to the method along with any other parameters that it needs (it is unclear if the id in the `AddServiceToInvoice` method is actually the `ser` parameter or not. This assumes it is not)

**Action Link In View**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Service", "Invoice", "AddServiceToInvoice", new {id = IdVariable, ser = Model.InvoiceId})
```

**AddServiceToInvoice Action Method**

```
public ActionResult AddServiceToInvoice(int id, int ser)
    {
        //Use the redirect to action helper and pass the ser variable back
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Invoice", new{ser = ser});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a link with that ID:

if you're doing a get-request that would be something like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add service to invoice", "Controller", "AddServiceToInvoice", 
new {id = Model.InvoiceViewModel.InvoiceId})
```

Otherwise if you want to do a post you need to create a form:

```
@using Html.BeginForm(action, controller, FormMethod.Post)
{
    <input type="hidden" value="@Model.InvoiceViewModel.InvoiceId" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add service to invoice" />
}
```